# Collections Sort and Binarysearch and lambda comparator

Tags: java, sorting, search, lambda, collections

I have an object Customer with an attribute id that is an int. I'm trying to use Collections builtin sort and search features with a lambda comparator. My question is, why does this seem to work:

```
Collections.sort(customers, (a, b) -> a.getID() - b.getID());
```

But this does not:

```
foundIndex = Collections.binarySearch(customers, custID, 
                    (a, b) -> a.getID() - b.getID());
```

When I say 'seem to work' I mean it runs with no errors.
Specifically with the second line, Eclipse has a problem with `.getID()` . It gave me a casting suggestion, which I tried:

```
foundIndex = Collections.binarySearch(customers, custID, 
                    (a, b) -> ((Customer) a).getID() - ((Customer) b).getID());
```

But that ran into a runtime error that said "Integer can not be cast to class Customer"
When I try to cast inside the `(a, b)` Eclipse doesn't like that either.
Will any lambda do what I want in the binarySearch part?

Comment: [`binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)) expects a value of the same type as your list elements, so you need to pass it a customer, not a customer's ID. Admittedly, I would be inclined to agree that the API is flawed (accepting a value of the key type makes more sense here), but that's Java for you.

Comment: omg, Thank you so much! That's all it was. Works great now. I found it so weird there is so much help regarding lambdas and sort, but nothing really on search. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commenter Silvio Mayolo stated, the problem isn't really the lambda it is what is expected by the key argument in `Collections.binarySearch()`.

This works exactly as I wanted:

```
//assumes presorted customers ArrayList, thank you commenter gOOse
public Customer findCustomer(int custID) {
        int foundIndex;
        Customer key = new Customer(custID, null);
        
        readLock.lock();
        try {
            foundIndex = Collections.binarySearch(customers, key, 
                (a, b) -> a.getID() - b.getID());       
            return (foundIndex > -1) ? customers.get(foundIndex) : null;
        }
        finally { readLock.unlock(); }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget that collections need to be sorted before binary searches work properly

Comment: Yes, this answer assumes the list is already sorted. This code is directly from what I am using, and the list is already sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried providing an instance of the Customer class instead of an ID?

```
foundIndex = Collections.binarySearch(customers, customer, 
                    (a, b) -> a.getID() - b.getID());
```

Comment: Yes, as per Silvio Mayolo's comment and my answer below.